# ¿ Como crear los enlaces para que puedan compartir mi sitio web?

Tags: javascript, html, css, redes-sociales

Tengo unos botones creados con la ayuda de `@Luis Daniel Rovira Contreras`, `@delCano`, `@azeós`, pero sigo buscando documentación de como crear el código necesario para que el visitante de mi sitio web, pueda compartirlo con los suyos.
Revise documentación de [developers facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters) sin mucho éxito, no se si tengo que crear una `API` de **faceebok** como para las aplicaciones.
Hace unos días revise un sitio donde detallaba como hacer el código de cada una de las redes sociales, pero no lo guarde y la perdí.
Lo que tengo esta sacado de [social_media_buttons en github](https://github.com/AlexSoicalap/social_media_buttons) , que es para compartir artículos específicos y no se si he de añadir todo los `<meta..../>`
para cada una de las redes.
¿ Donde podría encontrar  documentación que me ayude a conseguirlo.?
Gracias, dejo mi ejemplo.

```js
  $(window).on('load', function () {
  
    $(".loader-page").css({ visibility: "hidden", opacity: "0" }) ;

  });
    
    //script externo ///////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
    /*
Created by Alejandro Palacios https://github.com/AlexSoicalap
*/
$(function() {
 /*Define some constants */
 const ARTICLE_TITLE =  document.title;
 const ARTICLE_URL = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
 const MAIN_IMAGE_URL = encodeURIComponent($('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content'));

 $('.share-fb').click(function(){
  open_window('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+ARTICLE_URL, 'facebook_share');
 });

 $('.share-twitter').click(function(){
  open_window('http://twitter.com/share?url='+ARTICLE_URL, 'twitter_share');
 });

 $('.share-google-plus').click(function(){
  open_window('https://plus.google.com/share?url='+ARTICLE_URL, 'google_share');
 });

 $('.share-linkedin').click(function(){
  open_window('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='+ARTICLE_URL+'&title='+ARTICLE_TITLE+'&summary=&source=', 'linkedin_share');
 });

 $('.share-pinterest').click(function(){
  open_window('https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+ARTICLE_URL+'&media='+MAIN_IMAGE_URL+'&description='+ARTICLE_TITLE, 'pinterest_share');
 });
 
 $('.share-tumblr').click(function(){
  open_window('http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url='+ARTICLE_URL+'&name='+ARTICLE_TITLE+'&description='+ARTICLE_TITLE, 'tumblr_share');
 });

 function open_window(url, name){
  window.open(url, name, 'height=320, width=640, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no');
 }
});
```

```css
  .loader-page {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 25000;
   background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   transition: all .3s ease;
  }

  .loader-page::before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   border: 2px solid rgb(50, 150, 176);
   width: 60px;
   height: 60px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-left: 2px solid rgba(50, 150, 176, 0);
   border-top: 2px solid rgba(50, 150, 176, 0);
   animation: rotarload 1s linear infinite;
   transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  @keyframes rotarload {
   0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
   }
   100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
   }
  }

  .loader-page::after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   border: 2px solid rgba(50, 150, 176, .5);
   width: 60px;
   height: 60px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-left: 2px solid rgba(50, 150, 176, 0);
   border-top: 2px solid rgba(50, 150, 176, 0);
   animation: rotarload 1s ease-out infinite;
   transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
    
    /*estilos externos  
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
    /*
Created by Alejandro Palacios https://github.com/AlexSoicalap
*/

.share-buttons-row{
    height: 40px;

 display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.share-buttons-row >div:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
    border-radius: 100px;
  }

.share-buttons-row > div {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;

 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 margin-right: .3em;
 padding: 0;
 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
}


/*share row buttons
.share-buttons-row{
    height: 40px;

 display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    /*-webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
   /* display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.share-buttons-row >div:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    border-radius: 100px;
  }

.share-buttons-row > div {
 width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;

 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 margin-right: .3em;
 padding: 0;
 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}

*/
.share-fb{
    background-color: #2d609b;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-twitter{
    background-color: #00c3f3;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-google-plus{
    background-color: #eb4026;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-linkedin{
    background-color: #0074a1;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-pinterest{
    background-color: #ca212a;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-tumblr{
    background-color: #36465d;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--
Created by Alejandro Palacios https://github.com/AlexSoicalap
-->
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <title>[ARTICLE_TITLE]</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

 <!-- Some Open Graph tags -->
 <meta name="description" content="[ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION]">
 <meta name="author" content="[AUTHOR_NAME_OF_THE_ARTICLE]">
 <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
 <meta property="og:title" content="[ARTICLE_TITLE]" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="[ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION]" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="[ARTICLE_URL]" />
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="[WEBSITE_NAME]" />
 <meta property="article:publisher" content="[https://www.facebook.com/USERNAME]" />
 <meta property="article:published_time" content="[PUBLISHED_TIME_OF_YOUR_ARTICLE Ex: 2015-12-08T20:50:00Z]" />
 <meta property="og:image" content="[MAIN_IMAGE_URL]" />


 <meta name="twitter:title" content="[ARTICLE_TITLE]" />
 <meta name="twitter:description" content="[ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION]" />
 <meta name="twitter:image" content="[MAIN_IMAGE_URL]" />
 <meta name="twitter:site" content="@[TWITTER_USERNAME]" />
 <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@[TWITTER_USERNAME]" />
 <meta name="twitter:via" content="[TWITTER_USERNAME]" />
 <meta name="twitter:card" content="photo" />
 <meta name="twitter:url" content="[ARTICLE_URL]" />
 <!--
     <meta name="twitter:image:width"   content="550"/>
     <meta name="twitter:image:height"   content="750"/>
  -->
</head>

<body>
 <div class="loader-page"></div>
  
 <!-- Buttons, Copy this to your Page Article -->
 <div class="share-buttons-row">
  <!--Facebook's Button -->
  <div class="share-fb"></div>
  <!--Twitter's Button -->
  <div class="share-twitter"></div>
  <!--Facebook's Button -->
  <div class="share-google-plus"></div>
  <!--Linkedin's Button -->
  <div class="share-linkedin"></div>
  <!--Pinterest's Button -->
  <div class="share-pinterest"></div>
  <!--Tumblr's Button -->
  <div class="share-tumblr"></div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="./js/functions.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que las personas puedan compartir tu sitio debes usar los enlaces para compartir de cada red social:

```
<a href="//www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={URL}" class="facebook">Facebook</a>

<a href="//twitter.com/share?url={URL}" class="twitter">Twitter</a>

<a href="//plus.google.com/share?url={URL}" class="google-plus">Google +1</a>
```

Donde `{URL}` es la url que quieres compartir.

Si quieres que tus botones tengan contadores entonces si necesitarás hacer uso del SDK de cada red social. En éste [pen](https://codepen.io/graygilmore/pen/oclvb) puedes ver como hacerlo (créditos a su autor).

Comment: Gracias @Mariano Córdoba, pero no funciona el ejmplo de codepen, el codigo css me da errores y no salen los botones. Pero ya he pillado la idea y funcionamiento